# how to get token or req.query.id in post method?

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

how to get token or req.query.id in post method?

```
router.route('/reset')
  .get(isNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    token = req.query.id;
    console.log(token);
    res.render('reset');
  })
  .post(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
            console.log(token);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we transfer data through body in **POST** method.

And access the data by: `req.body`

But for token, I believe it is sent via **Header**.

To get header data, use `req.headers`